# How to take Database backup without using phpmyadmin in Mysql Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to take database backup from my phpmyadmin. Because of some issue, I am not able to start my Xampp control panel. That's why I am not able to open phpmyadmin panel.

Please give me an idea to take backup.

Comment: copy `xampp\mysql\data` folder. it has all your databases.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Heidi SQL](http://www.heidisql.com/). Its a great tool and also **more prerformant** instead of `phpmyadmin` over the browser.

You can connect to your DB and export your entire DB, or single tables, or single rows in different formats. I'm using it with MySQL and MSSQL databases.

You can do also other useful operations with it.