# How to Take Database Backup without using phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I take backup of  all tables of a database from ftp without using phpmyadmin and get the backup as a .sql file ??

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185564/how-to-take-database-backup-without-using-phpmyadmin-in-mysql-xampp

Comment: [**mysqldump -- A Database Backup Program**  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This script would do whatever you need. 
MySQL connections need to be improved though, but works fine.

```
<?php
// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/**
 * Define database parameters here
 */
define("DB_USER", '');
define("DB_PASSWORD", '');
define("DB_NAME", '');
define("DB_HOST", '');
define("OUTPUT_DIR", '');
define("TABLES", '*');

/**
 * Instantiate Backup_Database and perform backup
 */
$backupDatabase = new Backup_Database(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$status         = $backupDatabase->backupTables(TABLES, OUTPUT_DIR) ? 'OK' : 'KO';
echo "<br /><br /><br />Backup result: " . $status;

/**
 * The Backup_Database class
 */
class Backup_Database
{
  /**
   * Host where database is located
   */
  var $host = '';

  /**
   * Username used to connect to database
   */
  var $username = '';

  /**
   * Password used to connect to database
   */
  var $passwd = '';

  /**
   * Database to backup
   */
  var $dbName = '';

  /**
   * Database charset
   */
  var $charset = '';

  /**
   * Constructor initializes database
   */
  function Backup_Database($host, $username, $passwd, $dbName, $charset = 'utf8')
  {
    $this->host     = $host;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->passwd   = $passwd;
    $this->dbName   = $dbName;
    $this->charset  = $charset;

    $this->initializeDatabase();
  }

  protected function initializeDatabase()
  {
    $conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->passwd);
    mysql_select_db($this->dbName, $conn);
    if (!mysql_set_charset($this->charset, $conn)) {
      mysql_query('SET NAMES ' . $this->charset);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Backup the whole database or just some tables
   * Use '*' for whole database or 'table1 table2 table3...'
   * @param string $tables
   */
  public function backupTables($tables = '*', $outputDir = '.')
  {
    try {
      /**
       * Tables to export
       */
      if ($tables == '*') {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
          $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
      } else {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',', $tables);
      }

      $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' . $this->dbName . ";\n\n";
      $sql .= 'USE ' . $this->dbName . ";\n\n";

      /**
       * Iterate tables
       */
      foreach ($tables as $table) {
        echo "Backing up " . $table . " table...";

        $result    = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table);
        $numFields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        $sql .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . $table . ';';
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . $table));
        $sql .= "\n\n" . $row2[1] . ";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $sql .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' VALUES(';
            for ($j = 0; $j < $numFields; $j++) {
              $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
              $row[$j] = preg_replace("[^\r]\n", "\\n", $row[$j]);
              if (isset($row[$j])) {
                $sql .= '"' . $row[$j] . '"';
              } else {
                $sql .= '""';
              }

              if ($j < ($numFields - 1)) {
                $sql .= ',';
              }
            }

            $sql .= ");\n";
          }
        }

        $sql .= "\n\n\n";

        echo " OK" . "<br />";
      }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      var_dump($e->getMessage());
      return false;
    }

    return $this->saveFile($sql, $outputDir);
  }

  /**
   * Save SQL to file
   * @param string $sql
   */
  protected function saveFile(&$sql, $outputDir = '.')
  {
    if (!$sql)
      return false;

    try {
      $handle = fopen($outputDir . '/db-backup-' . $this->dbName . '-' . date("Ymd-His", time()) . '.sql', 'w+');
      fwrite($handle, $sql);
      fclose($handle);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      var_dump($e->getMessage());
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: -1, because the example code is way too verbose. The essence of the code, which is getting the table names via "SHOW TABLES" is deeply hidden among - in my opinion - irrelevant stuff: there are a ton of other pages discussing how to connect to a database or download text as file, plus the unnecessary 3 line comments, which add little to no extra information to the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`shell_exe()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to create the backup via PHP.

```
<?php
    $dbuser = ''; // database user
    $dbpass = ''; // database password
    $dbhost = ''; // database host
    $dbname = ''; // database name
    $create = shell_exec("mysqldump --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpass --host=$dbhost $dbname> mysql_dumb.sql");
    // header('Location: mysql_dumb.sql'); // you can optionally download it but secure access to the file before doing this
?>
```